# ModuleNotFoundError python - adding my modules directory to window's path doesn't work

Tags: python, import, module, path

I'm having a damn long issue for a while which doesn't let me import my own subscripts if they are not in the same directory.

I tried adding to path the folder, trying to copy the scripts to site-packages but nothing seems to work.

When I run my program, it says "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FortiAPP'" where FortiAPP is one of my modules that I want to import and the directory is in the system path and user path.

Please help! can't find how to fix this anywhere in this world :[

Comment: Hi nitayp1, welcome to Stack Overflow! To help us help you, can you describe what is the file location of the main module and the file location of the module you want to import?

Comment: I want the main module to be located on the desktop (simulate .exe program) , and all of the other files that i import should be somewhere else, no matter where , but nothing works out for me

Comment: It's way easier to have all the files in the same directory (where they can import each other) and put a shortcut on the desktop to the main module. Would that satisfy you?

Comment: Well I did that, but I'm practically learning python and developing automating tool in the same time and its not so comfortable to have all those files together in the same directory , I'd rather split them to groups of Projects and Learning directories and import each of them to another if necessary so that I can have only one single directory for python opened, and all other directories are for my current work job.